# Relative RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running a testing server on

```
http://localhost/test/
```

The .htaccess file I wish to use is located at

```
http://localhost/test/.htaccess
```

So the main directory of the website is

```
http://localhost/test/
```

I am using the following code, which works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]*)/$ /test/tempdir/show.php?var=$1 [L]
```

What I wish to do is remove the "test/" reference altogether since it is subject to change like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]*)/$ tempdir/show.php?var=$1 [L]
```

Although this seems to link to the correct place, it is not on the virtual server and thus gives a 404 error. So...

**The actual REDIRECT_URL:** (full local path)/tempdir/show.php?var=$1 (points to the right place, locally)

**The target REDIRECT_URL:** /test/tempdir/show.php?var=$1

With the target page being: http://localhost/test/tempdir/show.php?var=$1

I understand what I am trying to do is impractical, but bear with me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding a `RewriteBase /test`

Comment: Thanks, I did think of that, but the idea is to bypass it altogether so that if 'test' changes to 'test2', I wont need to update the .htaccess file.

Comment: Did the RewriteBase fix the problem, though? You could try putting a `RewriteBase /` in the htaccess that is in the root. I'm not sure if that works though.

Comment: Yes, RewriteBase / worked. Wish there was better way though. Thanks